# How to open a file or create it if it doesn't exist and fill it with values from the console

Tags: c++, file, fstream

My goal is to write a program that will check if a file is exist and if it contains the values. If it true, the program should read these values from the file into an array if not create a file if it didn't exist and write values to a file from the console. I write next code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char filename[] = "alphabet.txt";
    string alphabet;
    char ch;
    bool f;
    fstream fileWithAlphabet;

    fileWithAlphabet.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    (fileWithAlphabet.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()) ? f = true : f = false;

    if (f)
    {
        cout << "File empty, fill file" << endl;
        cout << "Fill the file with alphabet characters" << endl;
        cout << "please enter a single character, using q to stop: " << endl;
            for (;;) {
                cin >> ch;
                if (ch == 'q')
                    break;
                fileWithAlphabet << ch << "\n";
            }
        fileWithAlphabet.close();

    }
    else
    {    // use existing file
        cout << "success " << filename << " open. \n";
        cout << "read from a file";

        **** read into array ****        

        fileWithAlphabet.close();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please say, why after executing the code and output from the console, the file remains empty?

Answer (score 0):

After `peek` the file is in `eof` state and you can't write in it.

Set it at the beginning again:

```
    (fileWithAlphabet.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()) ? f = true : f = false;

    fileWithAlphabet.seekg (0);
```